# using facebook's formatting

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api

My question is is it possible to use facebook's formatting when it comes to using the graph API?

afs
dsaf
sda
fdf
sf
ds
adf
s
fadf
sdf
a

is how it appears on facebook but when I use the graph api to load it it shows:

afs dsaf sda fdf sf ds adf s fadf sdf a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are line feed characters in the response.  For example, I just tested it with my account and I got back this result:

```
"message": "test\n123\n456\n789"
```

All you would need to do is replace `\n` with `<br />` if you are rendering it on a web page.